# Terraform combining two variables into another variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How do i create another variable using two variables?
Ex- var.a + var.b = var.c?
var.s3_bucket_name + var. env = var.env.s3_bucket_name?

Comment: "${var.a}${var.c}"

Answer (score 1):

Its not possibile, as you can't create dynamic variables in TF. But you can create [local values](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals) dynamically:

```
locals {
   c = "${var.a}${var.b}" # assuming you want string concatenation
   s3_bucket_name = "${var.s3_bucket_name}-${var. env}"
}
```